# Which approach promises better performance - a megaquery or several targeted queries?

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, database-performance, query-performance

I am creating an SSRS report that returns data for several "Units", which are all to be displayed on a row, with Unit 1 first, to its right Unit 2 data, etc.

I can either get all this data using a Stored Proc that queries the database using an "IN" clause, or with multiple targeted ("Unit = Bla") queries.

So I'm thinking I can either filter each "Unit" segment with something like "=UNIT:[Unit1]" OR I can assign a different Dataset to each segment (witht the targeted data).

Which way would be more "performant" - getting a big chunk of data, and then filtering the same thing in various locations, or getting several instances/datasets of targeted data?

My guess is the latter, but I don't know if maybe SSRS is smart enough to make the former approach work just as well or better by doing some optimizing "behind the scenes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on how big the big chunk of data is. My experience has been that SSRS can process quite a large amount of data after it comes back from the database, and it does it quickly. If the report is going to aggregate the data in the end, I try to do as much of that as I can on the database end. The reason, usually the database server has more resources to do all that work. But, if the detail is needed, and you can aggregate on the report server end easily enough, pull 10K records and do it to it.

I lean toward hitting the database as few times as possible, but sometimes it just makes sense to get the data I need with individual queries. I have built reports with over 20 datasets, each for very specific measures that just didn’t union up really well. Breaking it up like this took the report run time from 3 minutes, to 20 seconds.

Not a great answer if you were looking for which exact solution to go with. It depends on the situation. Often, trial and error gets you to the answer for the report in question.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is not going to do any "optimizing" and the rendering requirements sound trivial, so you should probably consider this as SQL query issue, not really SSRS.

I would expect the single SELECT with an IN clause will be faster, as it will require fewer I/Os on the database files.  An SP is not required, you can just write a SELECT statement.

A further benefit is that you will be left with N-times less code to maintain (where N = the number of Units), and can guarantee the consistency of the code/logic across Units.

Comment: No, it definitely needs to remain an SP; it's humongous and uses temp tables, local variables (if that's what they're called in SQLese), etc. I didn't write it and don't grok it, so there's not much I can do to optimize it - "it is what it is"

Comment: That sounds like a reckless approach - your report will be at the mercy of whatever logic it uses, and you will be blamed as the report author. Good luck!